# Blank Cell = Empty. Instead of = 0?

Tags: excel

How Do i make a Blank Cell = Empty. Instead of = 0 ? But Also make sure the Cells with Data = the data?

---

Sheet1 A2:

=Sheet2!A2

Which Gives me a "0"

I want that Zero to be blank. But if that Cell on Sheet 2 isn't blank, then i want it to give me the Data that's in the cell on Sheet 2.

Thank

Answer (score 2):

You can test for blanks first:

```
=IF(Sheet2!A2="","",Sheet2!A2)
```

If you know the cells should contain text rather than numbers, you can just use:

```
=Sheet2!A2&""
```

Comment: Edit: the first one works: 

=IF(Sheet2!A2="","",Sheet2!A2)

Thank you Rory!

Comment: Is there a way to apply that logic to every cell on the workbook other than Row 1?

Comment: Just copy/paste or fill the formula as needed.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I'd upvote you but I don't have the reputation. I appreciate it.

Also if you want to message me, I'd like to add you on LinkedIn just incase I ever build a mega-multibillion dollar project. Just saying..

Comment: Done, and thank you.